# Oracle - Integer datatype precision max? I'm able to enter more than 38 numbers into a integer field

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have an integer column, and according to others an integer is supposed to have a precision of 38 and is basically an alias for the type delcaration of `Number(38)`

I'm sure I'm missing something, but how am I able to enter 128 digits into an INTEGER column?

```
CREATE TABLE TEST
(
  ID_INT  INTEGER                               NOT NULL
);

insert into test( id_int)
values ( '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890129010');
```

Version:  Oracle 11

Answer (score 3):

`INTEGER` is actually an alias for `NUMBER` (which can also be written as `NUMBER(*)`) and not `NUMBER(38)`. `NUMBER` on its own means no precision and you can store any value. The `38` is a guarantee of 38 digits of precision to allow portability between different systems running Oracle though it will happily allow numbers that are a lot higher - just don't expect it to always port correctly if you ever have to. I created a test table:

```
create table TESTNUM
(
  ID_INT     integer
 ,ID_NUM38   number(38)
 ,ID_NUM     number(*)
);
```

And here is a query to show the precisions stored:

```
select CNAME, COLTYPE, WIDTH, SCALE, PRECISION
  from COL
 where TNAME = 'TESTNUM';
```

I get back:

```
+----------+---------+-------+-------+-----------+
|  CNAME   | COLTYPE | WIDTH | SCALE | PRECISION |
+----------+---------+-------+-------+-----------+
| ID_INT   | NUMBER  |    22 |     0 |           |
| ID_NUM38 | NUMBER  |    22 |     0 |        38 |
| ID_NUM   | NUMBER  |    22 |       |           |
+----------+---------+-------+-------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 2):

You can insert the row.  But the data itself is then truncated.  For example, note that the last 2 digits are lost when I query the data

```
SQL> insert into test( id_int )
  2    values( 123456789012345678901234567890123456789012 );

1 row created.

SQL> select id_int from test;

                                                ID_INT
------------------------------------------------------
            123456789012345678901234567890123456789000
```

Comment: Why doesn't it throw an "numeric overflow" error?  I almost expect that it would.

Comment: Also, after querying the "128" numbers in my insert statement, my select query returns the following: 1.23456789012346E125

Comment: @contactmatt - I'm not sure off the top of my head why it rounds the data rather than throwing a numeric overflow exception.  As for the display, SQL*Plus is showing you the data in scientific notation.  You can change the formatting (`sql> column id_int format 999999999...` to 99 digits).  I don't see a way to get SQL*Plus to try to display numbers with more than 100 digits without using scientific notation which is why I used a smaller number in my example.

Answer (score 0):

I believe precision refers to maximum number of significant digits

Not the same thing as only allowing 38 length number.

See here for [explanation of significant digits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures).